# on Keyup or Change to give real-time image output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have an input that returns an image `URL` with `ID` `SomeImageUpload`. After upload the input looks like;

```
<div class="uploaded-some-image has_image">
  <input name="SomeImageUpload" value="SomeImageID" type="hidden">
  <img data-name="image" src="SomeImageUrl"/>
</div>
```

And I want to display in real-time `SomeImageUrl` to the `background: url()` of `div` with `ID` `SomeImage`

```
<div id="SomeImage" style="background: url('SomeImageURL')"></div>
```

I use the below for real-time update of content within text and select inputs but cannot get to work within the `style="background: url();"`

```
$(function() {
    $('#SomeImageUrl').bind('change keyup', function() {
        $('#SomeImage').text($(this).val());
    }).keyup();   
});
```

Must be in real-time, therefore as the image is changed it instantly updates the `style="background: url();"`. PHP functions are okay too if that gives a better response. Cheers.

[image]

Comment: How should the keyup function work on a hidden input field?

Comment: you're trying to bind a keyup event to an element with id SomeImageUrl.  That doesn't exist.

Comment: There is an upload anchor that opens a separate uploader and returns the value to the hidden input. The change event is within the `input` `value` and `img` `src`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try This :)**

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

**Happy Coding :)**